# What comic book story features Jake Radic and another character in space?

Tags: story-identification, comics

This concerns a comic I read as a child. It might have been Marvel or DC. It was in colour.

It concerns two characters, one of which was called Jake Radic. They are in space and they hit something. The story then shows them tumbling and tumbling until they land on solid ground. The one of the two characters says something like "Only the dead can see the... And we're not dead. OR ARE WE?" They are then depicted with hollowed-out eye sockets and a stark, reversed colours. I am not sure what it is they were supposed to have hit, something like a cosmic reef.

I have tried typing in Jake Radic into Google but unsurprisingly, all I got were lots of Serbian names! Possibly somebody remembers this particular very scary story. I think it is from the 1960s or thereabouts.

Comment: https://www.dccomics.com/characters/jay-garrick?

Comment: http://www.comicbookdb.com/browse.php?search=Character&letter=R

Comment: [John Radick](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Doom_Patrol_Vol_1_94)?