# Story about spacemen encountering city of the dead

Tags: story-identification

When I was a child I remember reading a story in a comic book about two spacemen who encounter a city in space that, legend has it, only the dead can see. The story ends with one of the spacemen questioning whether they were dead or not and how it was possible for them to see the mythical city. The comic book was in colour. I don't know if it was a Marvel comics publication or some other publisher. One of the spacemen's names was (I think) "Jake Radic"
If I try Googling this name, it comes up (not surprisingly) with lots of people from Serbia!

Comment: Is this the same id request as [your previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186599/58193)? If so this should really be deleted and if you have any new details to add [edit] the other post.